# Django: What's wrong with django-admin.py on Windows 7

Tags: python, django

On Windows XP I can open a command line, `cd` to a directory and type

```
django-admin.py startproject thesampleproject
```

but on my windows 7 machine, all I get is below. What happened? I successfully installed both Python and Django.

[image]

```
echo %path%
```

[image]

Comment: just out of curiosity (but it may also be what you need): can you try with "python django-admin.py startproject forum"? where python is the path to your python.exe executable (or just python.exe if you have it in your pythonpath)

Comment: I got a "Can't open file django-admin.py. No such file or directory". What should I do? =(

Comment: can you update your post with your path and pythonpath? (echo %path% and echo %pythonpath% from cmd. the latter may not be set, tho) also, how did you install django?

Comment: I installed Django by going to the unzipped directory and did a python setup.py install. I edited my question with result of %path% but %pythonpath% I get nothing.

Comment: this is why i love linux :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `ftype` and `assoc` values are set correctly:

```
> assoc .py
.py=Python.File
> ftype Python.File
Python.File="c:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Note especially that the Python.File line should end with `"%1" %*` otherwise you might end up with a situation like in the screenshot. To set the settings if they are wrong:

```
> assoc .py=Python.file
> ftype Python.File="c:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: I got a "File association not found for .extension py"

Comment: Apparently this is the right way to proceed tho, found this while trying to help you (i'm on unix, was following the standard linux approach of adding things to the paths) http://wiki.thinkhole.org/howto:django_on_windows it's a bit old, but if you read the section "Django and Vista" (last one) they propose the solution used by Bjorn

Answer (score 1):

I use windows 7 and the command `django-admin.exe` worked for me instead of `django-admin.py` Hope this info is useful to those who may need it....